# Cannot play videos in udemy

Tags: 20.04, midori

I am using Midori Browser and ubuntu 20.04 os but not able to play videos in udemy.com .
Please help me .

I already installed this package

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Please help me .

Answer (score -1):

For me it started to work on chrome but not on brave after I updated my nvidia driver on elementary os.
I hope you can solve it soon.
[Here are the libraries I installed](https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-elementary-os-5-juno/)